# Kendo Angular 2 Grid cannot updated to latest v0.19.1

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

As title says, I'm trying to update my kendo angular 2 Grid component to latest version. But npm only installs 0.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install 0.19.1, you need to tell npm to install the latest version else it will install the latest stable build

You can do `npm install @progress/kendo-angular-grid@0.19.1` to be exact or `npm install @progress/kendo-angular-grid@latest` to get the newest